# Can other people see Misaki?

Tags: another

So, I'm on episode 4, without spoilers, can you tell me if others can see her? It's kinda confusing to me.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to finish the anime first and ask for questions that will raise up after it? You'll just end up getting spoiled. Just saying, because I really hate spoilers.

Comment: lol: "without spoilers" you are asking for a fundamental part of the storyline up to now and you don't want to be spoilered? that's what i call hypocrisy

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> In episode **5**, you (the viewer) learn that the class is ignoring Misaki as part of a "countermeasure" to ward off the calamity that affects class 3-3 (which is what causes all the paranormal phenomena you see in episodes 1-4, e.g. the girl nearly getting crushed by the falling glass pane; the nurse in the crashing elevator; etc). The basic idea is that the class has one more person than it should (you find out why in episode **6**, I believe), and so by pretending that one of the people in the class doesn't exist, they bring the number of people in the class down to the correct number.